# java list implementation

Tags: java

I have the following use case:

- a list containing objects with various properties - e.g name,type,date
- the list can contain a lot of elements(50k - 200k)

I wanted to ask what would be the best list implementation for this situation given the fact that I need to do operations on the list such as

- order - e.g by type(alphabetically)
- filtering - e.g. by date
- no inserts
- sublists - similar to paging.

Thanks.

Comment: Objects with various properties, that means objects of unrelated classes, or objects of classes who share same superclass? Or you mean objects with properties of various values? Be more specific..

Comment: what about thread-safety? how many threads will populate it?

Comment: @SergeyBenner typically one, since it says 'no inserts'.

Comment: Yes it is a single thread that will populate the list.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the size of the list (or an upper bound) before-hand and can guarantee no insertions then you need to use ArrayList.

It is backed up by an array so lookups are fast.

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.ArrayList` seems best in this case (backed up by a vector). One thing that you need to do upfront is reserve enough space when constructing the instance (it's best if you know the number of elements beforehead), to avoid copying on resized vector allocations.

Another win compared to `LinkedList` is the absense of internode references which reduces the required heap size roughly twice compared to `ArrayList`.

- append: O(1) (given no inserts)
- ordering = sorting: O(n*log(n))
- filtering: O(n)
- sublist: O(1)

Answer (score 0):

A single collection type can't satisfy all of those use-cases. The nearest I can see is TreeSet.

- order - Implement your object to override equals and hascode based on type
- sublists - headSet, tailSet
- filtering - roll your won